# sql-ex exercise 39 failed on second server error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> Exercise 39:  Define the ships that "survived for future battles";
>   being damaged in one battle, they took part in another.

Database Schema: http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_3

My approach:

```
SELECT distinct o.ship from Outcomes o
WHERE o.RESULT = 'damaged' 
AND exists (select 1 FROM Outcomes o2 WHERE o2.ship = o.ship 
AND (o2.result='OK' OR o2.result='sunk'))
```

sql-ex says

> Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed
>   test on second, checking database

correct result matched with my output.

Where I failed?

Comment: One problem I see is that you haven't use the dates of the battles. Notice the "survived for **future** battles"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! needed to add Distinct

```
select distinct kk.ship from
(Select ship,date from outcomes oo,battles bb where oo.battle=bb.name) tt 
inner join 
(Select ship,date as damagedate from outcomes oo,battles bb where result='damaged' AND oo.battle=bb.name) kk 
ON tt.ship=kk.ship AND tt.date>kk.damagedate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with a as (select * from outcomes o join battles b on o.battle=b.name)select distinct a1.ship from a a1, a a2 where a1.ship=a2.ship and a1.result='damaged'and a1.date<a2.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    select o.ships from (select a.ships, a.battle from outcomes as a where result in (damaged, unharmed)) as o
    where o.battle <> a.battle
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct outcomes.ship
from outcomes, (select outcomes.ship, battles.[date], outcomes.result
            from outcomes, battles
            where battles.name = outcomes.battle
            and result = 'damaged' ) t1, 
 battles
where outcomes.ship = t1.ship and
outcomes.battle = battles.name and
battles.[date] > t1.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, and it is not resolved as true by the page, but i am not agreeing with it. Dont know what my solution is different then any of yours

```
select distinct damaged.ship from 
(Select oo.ship,date from outcomes oo
inner join battles bb on oo.battle=bb.name
) as ships
inner join (Select ship,date as damagedate from outcomes oo1
inner join battles bb1 on oo1.battle=bb1.name and result = 'damaged') as damaged
on (ships.ship = damaged.ship and ships.date != damaged.damagedate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the greatest design, but also worked for me:

```sql
with damaged as (Select b.date, o.ship
from outcomes o 
inner join battles b on b.name = o.battle
where result = 'damaged') 

Select distinct o.ship
from outcomes o 
right join damaged d on d.ship = o.ship
right join battles b on b.name = o.battle
where b.date > d.date
```